# why using @InitBinder setting autoGrowCollectionLimit not work?

Tags: spring

in  runtime at AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor class growCollectionIfNecessary method ,the autoGrowCollectionLimit still is 256.

```
    private void growCollectionIfNecessary(Collection<Object> collection, int index, String name,
        PropertyHandler ph, int nestingLevel) {

    if (!isAutoGrowNestedPaths()) {
        return;
    }
    int size = collection.size();
    if (index >= size && index < this.autoGrowCollectionLimit) {
        Class<?> elementType = ph.getResolvableType().getNested(nestingLevel).asCollection().resolveGeneric();
        if (elementType != null) {
            for (int i = collection.size(); i < index + 1; i++) {
                collection.add(newValue(elementType, null, name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in controller 
 using

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

my spring framework version is 4.3.2 
 I want to know  what's the right way of setting autoGrowCollectionLimit value

Answer (score 0):

I change the method to initListBinder,It's work

Comment: I got .https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1233/files,
should call setAutoGrowCollectionLimit before other configuration methods